# How do you change already printed text, then change it back again? (Python)

Tags: python, text

How would I go about changing printed text, before changing it back again?

ex. the word *"hello"* is printed, then for, let's say, a second the word *"world"* flashes, before going back to *"hello"*, basically, like it glitching out.

I've already tried using the **sys.stdout.flush()** function, but it doesn't seem to be working for me.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

So - the general solution for this would be to use curses (https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html).

For your relatively simple problem though, I think you can just write out a \r, and write over what you put there the first time.

```
# Untested and based on memory
while True:
    word = "world"
    sys.stdout.write("\rHello %s" % word)
    time.sleep(1)
    sys.stdout.write("\rHello %s" % (" " * len(word)))
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: You forgot to end the quotation mark on line 6

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Linux, then this is accomplished with the carriage return symbol, "\r". In general, "\r" is used to return a curser to the start of a line in a terminal, and the "\n" is used to move a curser down one unit in a terminal (different terminals and different OS might used these symbols differently). So in general, if we modify the print-end variable from "\n\r" to just "\r" we can over write lines. For example,

```
import time
print('hello',end='\r')
time.sleep(0.5)
print('hello world',end='\r')
time.sleep(0.5)
print('hello',end='\r')
```